# Why Parallel. ForEach is taking the same time as Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written an algorithm to solve Sudoku puzzle.
Now I have to read around 100 sudoku puzzles and solve them.

Basically I am just reading all the problems in 2d arrays and loop through each of them to solve them.

```
foreach (var problem in problems)
            {
                Solve(problem);  // Solve is a static method
            }
```

If I replace above piece of code with :

```
Parallel.ForEach(problems, problem => Solve(problem));
```

I donot set considerable improvement. I have 2 cores in my machine.
Am I missing anything , do I have to do anything else to make sure my algorithm is parallel and uses all cores.

Comment: Your problem probably is not hard enough

Comment: This question is unanswerable without the code that actually runs. The current code can be read from MSDN too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some overhead involved in setting up and managing the parallel tasks. This overhead would negate some of the gains you'd make in solving the problems. It's possible, if the code executes quickly enough, that this overhead might dominate the execution time. Moreover, with 2 cores, you'd only expect to see at best 2x improvement (half the time) since only 2 problems could be worked on at any given time.  Absent any information on your performance or code, it's difficult to say whether there is anything causing it to not be able to run in parallel (for example do you have critical sections that force serial execution).

Comment: It's not true that 2X improvement is the best possible. You can have more than two threads on two cores.

Comment: So? Where and when could they run??

Comment: @Daniel I'm assuming that this is a purely computational problem.  If there's no blocking, having more threads per core won't help.

Comment: @tvanfosson why do you assume that? It could very well be the case, but it is not necessarily.

Comment: Partly because doing I/O inside a parallel loop when the entire problem could be held in memory seems like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @tvanfosson . And another possibility is you have 2 cores so your one core is used on other things like your IDE, at least not 100% available to overcome the overhead of Parallel